# Add dot to numeric values after 10'th number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a numeric value that looks like this: `mynumber = 2006601400162797`
Is there any nice way to modify it so a dot is added after the 10'th number? Like this: `2006601400.162797`

Comment: convert it to string and manipulate it there.

Comment: If you try something and then ask a nicer way then it would be fair

Comment: Hey there @E.W, have a look at the help center's [guidelines for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be very useful, for instance, to see some code you have produced for others to have a starting point to help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
n = 2006601400162797

n2 = str(n)
n2 = float(n2[:10] + '.' + n2[10:])

# 2006601400.162797
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
n = 2006601400162797
div = float("1"+'0'*(len(str(n))-10))
print(n/div)
```

output:
    2006601400.162797

Answer (score 0):

```
mynumber = str(2006601400162797)

result=[]
[result.append(".") if len(result)==10 else result.append(x) for x in mynumber]
print("".join(result))
```

output

```
2006601400.162797
```